# Apache Kafka : centralization vs decentralization

Tags: apache-kafka

We need to make changes in our IT architecture by replacing jms queues synchronization with apache kafka topics, but we need the best practices between a central kafka platform that stands as a middleware between our systems, or multiple kafka platforms for each functionnal perimeter.

What is your feedback dear friends and best practices to optimize performance and to choose the optimal Kafka architecture with best standards. Thanks!